# How to install PHP 5.3 on CentOS 7 (troubleshooting propose)

Tags: centos, docker, php

I would like to install PHP 5.3 version in CentOS 7 for development propose. I know this PHP version has security problems but I need to validate why a bug happens with this version of PHP with a proprietary software.

Is there any way I can do this? I'm using Docker images to run the software. 
The following code is where in the Dockerfile php is being installed.

```
# Install Packages
RUN yum install -y curl vim git wget tar unzip nano gcc-c++ make mysql httpd && \
    yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm && \
    yum install -y http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm && \
    yum install yum-utils && \
    yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70 && \
    yum update -y && \ 
    yum install -y \
    php70-php.x86_64 \
    php70-php-bcmath.x86_64 \
    php70-php-cli.x86_64 \
    php70-php-common.x86_64 \
    php70-php-devel.x86_64 \
    php70-php-gd.x86_64 \
    php70-php-intl.x86_64 \
    php70-php-json.x86_64 \
    php70-php-mbstring.x86_64 \
    php70-php-mcrypt.x86_64 \
    php70-php-mysqlnd.x86_64 \
    php70-php-pdo.x86_64 \
    php70-php-pear.noarch \
    php70-php-xml.x86_64 \
    php70-php-ast.x86_64 \
    php70-php-opcache.x86_64 \
    php70-php-pecl-zip.x86_64 \
    php70-php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 && \
    yum clean all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be possible on CentOS 7. The earliest version of CentOS 7 (7.0.1406) was already shipped with version 5.4.16 of the `php` package. You can verify this against the [packages list in the CentOS Vault](http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/Packages/).

Remi's PHP repositories (the one currently mentioned in the Dockerfile) were intended to provide newer versions of PHP (>5.4) to CentOS. PHP 5.3 is not available from these repositories for CentOS 7.

You could get PHP 5.3 by rolling back to a CentOS 6 image. On DockerHub, the earliest available version of CentOS 6 is 6.6 (tagged with `centos:6.6` and `centos:centos6.6`). CentOS 6.6 comes with version 5.3.3 of the PHP package, which may be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks! Changing CentOS version works for me.